# print php result in a nice html table

Tags: php, html

my aim is to pull data from mysql and print it in html table. asumming that 1,2,3...8 are the data

```
<table style="width: 100%">
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>4</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>7</td>
 <td>8</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

this is the code i have so far but this will only print out the column but no the row. plz help. thank you

```
<table style="width: 100%; color:aqua">
<?php               
$showFoto = getFoto();
echo '<tr>';
foreach($showFoto as $Foto){
echo '<td class="afs"><img alt="" src="img/'.$Foto['img'].'.'.$Foto['ext'].'"><br>'.$Foto['about'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to wrap another loop around your <tr> just as you did with your <td>.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.print-r.php  if you go down there's a print_nice function. i used it for similar situations.

Comment: Your `echo '<tr>';` and `echo '</tr>';` are outside of any loop structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
 <table width ="100%" style="color:aqua" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
 <?php               
    $showFoto = getFoto();
    $i=0;
    foreach($showFoto as $Foto){
      ++$i;
      echo ($i%4==0) ? '</tr><tr>' :'';
      echo '<td class="afs">
            <img alt="" src="img/'.$Foto['img'].'.'.$Foto['ext'].'">'.$Foto['about'].
           '</td>';         
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
 </table>
```